# Edit attributes of a child model from the form representing parent model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have a person model with different attributes. A person has an Address, which is a OneToOneField for the Person/parent model. When i go for admin form in adding/editing the person, i also need to edit the address attributes like line1, line2, mobile and so on. Similarly, i want to delete some person from the admin page and it should delete the matching references like address as well. I have already tried lots of things, including Inline and all. But, i think inline could have worked only if the address would be having a foreign key with the person, reverse was not possible. Any kind of help on this would be highly appreciated...

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_Id = models.CharField(max_length=32L, primary_key=True, db_column='PERSON_ID', editable=False)
    business_Address = models.OneToOneField(Address, unique=True, db_column='BUSINESS_ADDRESS_ID')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PD_PERSON' 

class Address(models.Model):
    # Field names made lowercase.
    address_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ADDRESS_ID')
    address_name = models.CharField(max_length=256L, db_column='NAME', blank=True)
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=128L, db_column='LINE1', blank=True)
     class Meta:
        db_table = 'PD_ADDRESS'
```

In admin.py ~

```
class PersonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('customer_Id', 'complete_Name', 'company')
    search_fields = ('name', 'customer_Id', 'email_Id')

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ PersonInline, ]

admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
#admin.site.register(Category)
#admin.site.register(Languages)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Please, show your models and what you've tried.

Comment: class Person(models.Model):
    person_Id = models.CharField(max_length=32L, primary_key=True, db_column='PERSON_ID', editable=False)
    business_Address = models.OneToOneField(Address, unique=True, db_column='BUSINESS_ADDRESS_ID')....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PD_PERSON'

Comment: class Address(models.Model):
    address_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ADDRESS_ID') # Field name made lowercase.
    address_name = models.CharField(max_length=256L, db_column='NAME', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=128L, db_column='LINE1', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PD_ADDRESS'

Comment: In admin.py ----                                                      class PersonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('customer_Id', 'complete_Name', 'company')
    search_fields = ('name', 'customer_Id', 'email_Id')

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PersonInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
#admin.site.register(Category)
#admin.site.register(Languages)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)

Comment: Hey @naw and welcome to Stack Overflow :) - another time do put code in the question itself (you can edit your questions). I've done it for you this time to make it easier for people to read.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** delete adress on person deletion

You can use post_delete signal to automatically delete the adress once your person is deleted. It's quite simple to use

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from web.programing.roxx.models import Person, Adress

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Person, dispatch_uid="person_post_delete")
def onPersonDelete(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    # be carefull, the instance doesn't exist anymore in the database
    adress_id = instance.business_Address.id
    if id != None:
        Adress.objects.filter(id=adress_id).delete()
```

But this won't display the adress in the "Are you sure ?" message..

---

**Problem 2:** edit the adress in the person admin page

For the moment, I don't see any solution simpler than building a custom form to edit Person model, and override both add_view() and change_view() methods to initialize this form withe the O2O key..

Comment: May i know if ModelInline will help in this case. If yes, where am i doing wrong. If not, is there a hack to it? I think inline supports only when foreign key is in child model or the edit/add for django admin works only for parent models and not the associated child models..